# Automatically publish JavaDoc as a functioning website on remote machine

Tags: maven, repository, javadoc, nexus

Is there a way of automatically publishing as live website javadocs after uploading it to Nexus Maven repository? I have some packages, which are under constant development and I'd like to have the docs for them available for browsing by other team members straight after uploading updated code to our remote repository.

Is there any ready solution for doing that or would I have to write say a shell script (executed by Maven after successfull deployment of the code to the remote repo), which would copy the docs to a remote location on a web server?

I know that Nexus Professional allows to view javadocs out of the box, but even for 10 users it is a bit pricey, so I'd appreciate a different solution :-)

I'm using Eclipse@Windows + Maven 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

If your project is open-source and is released to [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/) then your javadoc will be available at [javadoc.io](http://www.javadoc.io) automatically.

The url is of the form:  `http://www.javadoc.io/doc/[groupId]/[artifactId]`. For example, I have my javadoc for my project at [www.javadoc.io/doc/me.ramswaroop.jbot/jbot](http://www.javadoc.io/doc/me.ramswaroop.jbot/jbot)

Comment: Wow, javadoc.io is incredible. Thanks.

Comment: What if your project is not open source and want to deploy to an internal file server?

Comment: Apparently this works for any docs that are archived in a `*-javadoc.jar` file and have an `index.html`.

Answer (score 2):

Nexus Open Source as well as Nexus Professional support the site repository format, which allows you to host Maven produced sites. If you set up publishing a Maven site that includes Javadoc as part of your build you can have them accessible there.

The other thing you can do is just publish javadoc and source artifacts as part of you build and then Eclipse will be able to automatically download them from Nexus and you therefore wont even need a website with the javadoc on it for you developers.

Of course other people might want the site though.

Documentation on all that is available [in the Nexus book as usual](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/sites.html).

Answer (score 1):

A bit late for reply, but someone else might need it in future. I didn't try the solution you proposed instead using one utilizing Maven Wagon plugin. Basically I first upload the jar with javadoc to webserver using sftp protocol and then unzip it using ssh command.

So parts of my parent POM, which configure the plugin look as follows:

```
   <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>wagon-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>upload-javadoc</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>upload</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>my_id</serverId>
                            <fromDir>${local.dir}</fromDir>
                            <includes>${javaDoc.file}</includes>
                            <excludes>pom.xml</excludes>
                            <url>${remote.url}</url>
                            <toDir>${remote.dir}</toDir>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>execute-test-commands</id>
                        <phase>deploy</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>sshexec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <serverId>my_id</serverId>
                            <url>${remote.url}</url>
                            <commands>
                                <command>mkdir -p ${www.dir}</command>
                                <command>unzip -o ${remote.dir}/${javaDoc.file} -d ${www.dir} > latest_unzip_log.txt</command>
                            </commands>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

And then just call the plugin in child pom:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

So that's my solution, but I guess Manfred's is much simpler.

Ps.
Having the Javadoc available only in Ecplise (which I do anyways) was not the goal as the purpose was for the Javadoc to be available for other project members through a website.

Comment: I hope this works. This seems to be what I need. I want to have Javadocs deployed with each build to an internal file server so other devs can have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to host javadocs is https://docshoster.org/. It can automatically pickup from maven. There is an api to upload directly as well.